# Is there a way to make escaping characters work in Vue.js in this case?

Tags: vue.js

I have a string with escaping characters in it, it comes from props as a property of an object

```
string: "A text \"escaped\" text"
```

I want to display it in the template but when I'm using it like
`<span v-html="prop.string"></span>`

it shows up with backslashes in my template

I don't understand why this is happening and how can it be fixed? I thought v-html would display the string without \"

**UPD**

The only thing I came up with is to change `\"` to `"` using regex

Comment: you could do `string: 'A text "escaped" text'`

Comment: @depperm format of the string can not be changed I'm afraid.

Comment: I very much doubt this is a Vue problem, there must be slash characters in your strings. Slashes in string literals or JSON strings will be interpreted as escape sequences when they are parsed and don't feature in the string that is created. If those extra slashes aren't being inserted by code that you have control over then you're going to have to use remove them yourself. You will need to understand where the extra slashes come from to be able to 'decode' them correctly.

Comment: The simplest and easiest solution is the one of @depperm

Answer (score 0):

`v-html` will not add escape characters.  Your text input must have already been escaped; The source that provides the property has already escaped the text before it is sent in as a property.

You need to fix that before the value is sent in, or by unescaping in your consuming component by adding a computed property, or creating a filter.

See this pen.  https://codepen.io/Flamenco/pen/xovKLq

```js
        <div v-html='message'></div>
        <div v-html='message2'></div>
        <div v-html='message3'></div>
        <div v-html='computed3'></div>

    data: () => ({
        message: "Hello \"World\"",
        message2: `Hello \"World\"`,
        message3: 'Hello \\"World\\"', // this one is your property.
      }),

    computed: { 
     computed3() {
          return this.message3.replace(/\\"/g, '"');
        }
    }
```

I recommend dealing with this by fixing the source though...

Answer (score 0):

you can use innerText or :innerText on your div like so

```html
<div innerText="String with </> which won't be interpreted" />
```

or

```html
<!-- specialText: 'String with </> which won't be interpreted', -->

<div :innerText="specialText" />
```

If you know that you will need special characters at the beginning or the end of the sentence, you can use ::before or ::after, special characters won't be interpreted either.

```css
nav a::before {
    content: '<';
}

nav a::after {
    content: '/>';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use double slashes like `\\`